# Hiding number in large pointer array by modifying least significant bit of elements

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Straight of the bat I will say I barely know what I'm doing here - I'm having a major trouble grasping bitwise operators in C.  As an exercise in one of my courses I'm supposed to hide a number (unsigned int) in large pointer array (unsigned char) containing numbers. I'm doing it using srand (with key, so that I can decode it later) to choose specific elements of the array and then take one bit of the number I'm supposed to hide (iterating through all the bits) and changing the least significant bit of the array element. The choosing elements.

While I get the general idea I cannot, despite googling, figure out the bit operations. So having the `size` that I'm supposed to encode in i-th run of the loop (`i-th` bit of size) and randomly chosen `current_element` this is what I came up with to get the bit and then alter the element.

```
for (i=0; i<32; i++){    
    tmp = rand() % max;
    current_element = array[tmp];
    current_element ^= ((size >> i)  & 0x01)<<7;
}
```

To decode I would write it analogically (where size is wiped unsigned char that I'm trying to write the decoded number to):

```
for (i=0; i<32; i++){
        tmp = rand() % max;
        current_element = array[tmp];
        size = size ^ ((current_pixel.blue<<0)<<7);

    }
```

These two are in diffrent functions and `srand()` is seeded anew in each of them beforehand.

But these are clearly not working and I don't even know which one (I can only check if it decoded correctly). Truth be told these are mostly copied from other things I found online as so far operating on individual bits eludes me. So I'd be grateful for some sort of advice on what is wrong here (and I'm aware probably everything is wrong here and it's all gibberish but I've been trying to fix it to no avail for quite a while now).

Comment: Your question is too broad, and looks like a homework dump more than a genuine question. If you do not understand bitwise operations, isolate that particular part of the problem, write code to the best of your ability, demonstrate efforts and than people will be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Alternatively, think about what aspect(s) of bitwise operators are troubling you, and ask specifically about those.  Or search for those -- you are more likely to find what you're looking for if you're looking for something specific.  Or even consider reading the relevant section of your textbook and reviewing your class notes.

Comment: No, this is part of a larger program I'm trying to write, encoding and decoding secret messages with key in images - unfortunately to do that I need to understand three things - how to isolate one specific bit, then how to change last bit, then how to add diffrent bits together when forming.
There is no textbook I could browse since I don't have one and class notes and lectures are lacking due to our not entirely good lecturer who has only glanced over this topic. Still, thank you, I'll try to experiment more and pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only going to indirectly answer your question. I'm going to give you some gentle advice that many new programmers need.
  If you want to learn to program,  *Stop googling and Think.*

Break the problem down into steps. Write pseudocode:

```
  encode:
     for each bit in message_word:
        select random array element
        if bit is set:
           toggle LSB of element.

  decode:
     for each bit in message_word:
        select random element
        if LSB is toggled:
           set bit in message_word
```

Now, write the C code for each of those steps.  You actually have most of the pieces.

```
 // for each bit in message_word
 for (i=0;i<sizeof(message_word); i++) {
   // select random array element
   tmp = rand() % max;
   current_element = array[tmp];
   // if bit is set:
   if ( bit_is_set(message_word,i) ) {
       // toggle LSB of element.
       toggle_lsb(current_element);
   }
 }
```

Now that you are down to basic steps, maybe you can google ["how to toggle a bit"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/10396).  But make sure you understand the answer before plugging it in.

```
int bit_is_set(word,bit) { return ((word>>bit)&0x01); }
int toggle_lsb(word) { return word ^ 1; }
```

However - this still won't work.  Why?  Time to think again.  You made a copy of the value at the randomly selected array index.  You toggled a bit in the copy.  What effect is that going to have on the array?

Solve that and there's at least one more challenge. In the decode function, how will you implement `is_lsb_toggled`?  How will you know if a given bit was supposed to be 1 or 0?  You have all the information you need. Good Luck.

Comment: "If you want to learn to program, Stop googling and Think."  +100 for this.